# Change Android EditText background color

Tags: android, background, android-edittext

I am developing an Android app. There's this issue with the EditTexts, because in some devices the "background" is white (which is the way I want it), but on others is transparent, and makes the app less professional. Here's an image with the "white background":

[image]

On other devices the edit texts that say "Yo" and "Casa" are transparent, so the words mix with the map and its pretty awful. 
I have tried changing the background color in the android layout xml. The closest one was I believe @drawable/white, but slightly changes the position and size of the edit text, making them look like they're one and its even worst.
Here is an example:

[image]

Is there a nice way to approach this problem? I read somewhere that an option was to add a white background image to the edit texts, but seemed like a lot of trouble.

**UPDATE**

I tried adding a background image, but its the same as changing the background color to any color using the android:background, the edit texts get like smaller or something. I added a blue "delimiter" to the image and this is the result:

[image]

But I want them like in the first picture, not so close one to another.

This would be the code of the edittext layout XML, the other one looks very similar. Only by adding the android:background tag changes from picture 1, to picture 3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why don't you try setting the background of EditText programmatically?

```
yourEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

or...

```
yourEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can add android:background="@drawable/white" attribute to your  element in layout xml. You can use a lot of color resource between the double quotes (like from Android color resources).

Comment: I said above that thats exactly what I tried but completely changed the look of the edittexts, giving an unwanted result

Comment: sorry but you said you did that in the manifest :D 
try to add a picture with a solid color you want and make it the background of the edit text, it won't change in any circumstances.

Comment: Hahah true, I edited it (Ive been programming for hours and I got a mess in my head). I will try that, hope its not too difficult

Comment: Did you try #ffffffff?

Comment: and?  using a color, not a drawable, should not affect the size of the EditText, but should make the bg solid white.  did that not work?

Comment: It didnt work, it did change the size of the edit text (as shown in the last picture, but without the blue lines)

Comment: yes man i know that feeling :D 
after i made a nice answer supported with images of what i did with this example i found that i can't put images in my answer until i get 10 reputation :(

Comment: it worked for me but unfortunately i can't show you.

Comment: @Code-Blaster Alright! there goes one of the edittexts layout xml. My mail is vecman_2@hotmail.com in case you can send me the solution over there. Also I upvoted your answer so I think you can post now pictures

Answer (score 0):

Put the following image which has a solid white background in the drawable folder (it may not appear because it's white and this page's background is white also) right click under this paragraph and select "Save Image as".

[image]

And refer to it in your layout and you will get a result like the following image

[image]